# SlideToggle elements with same class and same script

Tags: jquery

How can I use `this` in jQuery to be able to click on the `+` sign to slideToggle the `.expand` element? I want to make the code simple and use the same script for all articles on the page. One solution would be to use a unique id for each articles element and detect each click for that id, but then I guess the script would be unnecessary big and complicated.

How can I improve my script below to be able to use it for several articles? Perhaps it would be easier/better to use `slideDown` and `slideUp` instead of `slideToggle`?

```
<article class="post">
    <header>
        <h2>Headline</h2>
    </header>
    <img src="images/test.jpg">
    <div class="expand">Text</div>
    <div class="click">+</div>
</article>

<article class="post">
    <header>
        <h2>Headline</h2>
    </header>
    <img src="images/test.jpg">
    <div class="expand">Text</div>
    <div class="click">+</div>
</article>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".expand").hide();
    $(".click").click(function(){ 
        $(".expand").slideToggle();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use DOM traversal to find the related `.expand` from the clicked `.click` element.

You can use the `this` keyword within the click handler to get a reference to the `.click`  element which raised the event. From there you can use the `prev()` method to find the required `.expand`. Try this:

```
$(".click").click(function(){ 
    $(this).prev('.expand').slideToggle();
});
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/m7zmn6q8/)

Also note that it's better practice to use CSS to set the initial state of the elements in the page.

Comment: Thanks! This is working perfect! I guess if I swap place with the .expand and .click element, I would use Next() instead?

Comment: Yes, that would work. You could use `siblings('.expand')` too if you don't care about the order the elements are in, so long as they are a direct child of the same element.

Comment: I know this is a new question, but I just wonder if it possible to slide back an article if someone is opened, when a new article is opened? Would it be very complicated?

Comment: That's simple enough to do, just call `slideUp()` on all `.expand` elements before you toggle the current one: https://jsfiddle.net/m7zmn6q8/3/ The stop is used to cancel the animation when toggling the current element.

Comment: It's working perfect! Great! Just wonder it there will be any performance issue if all slideUp() are called for all .expand element if I have several elements? There will always only be one element to close when a new element is expanded, but will the code run slideUp() on all element despite that they are closed or does jQuery affect only the one that is opened? Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This code get the parent element of the clicked element wich has the .click class and find the child element wich has the .expand class.

```
$("body").on("click", ".click", function(){
     $(this).parent().children(".expand").slideToggle();
});
```